# HTML overflow not working for TD and overflow concept for TR

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;">    
    <tr>
        <td width="221" style="overflow:hidden">
            //A very long text that meant to overflow
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

After some research, the above code should works fine but it's not. It can only be achieved if there is an extra `div` tag with style `overflow:hidden` in `td`.

And another question is how to implement an overflow to height? Would be appreciate if any sample code can be provided.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify more details to your object, like white-space, because the ling text is automatically wrap in td.

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;">    
<tr>
    <td width="221" style="overflow:hidden;display:block;width:5em;white-space:nowrap;background-color:#ccc;">
        //A very long text that meant to overflow
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the TD should solve it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cYAMm/

Answer (score 0):

For controlling **hight only** u have to use the CSS property `overflow-y` in place of `overflow`. To apply scrolling u have to use `overflow-y: scroll` and similar to that of `overflow` for other such cases.

Answer (score 0):

## [Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/apxx7/1/)

you can emulate overflow:hidden without alterate table-layout, just putting inside the TD two divs:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 320px; height: 150px;">

    content

  </div>
</div>
```

See yor code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apxx7/1/)

Comment: you don't need to add position absolute

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have overflow for the specific width and height, you should add css property `display:block` to `<td>` and as others said before for width overflow you should set `white-space:nowrap` it prevent your text to be wrap ,[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shirin_Abdolahi/dSmEE/) is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Shirin_Abdolahi/dSmEE/) with `overflow:scroll` for better underestanging